# Arduino COM ports grayed out

Tags: arduino, usb, arduino-uno

I am unable to choose a COM port in the arduino IDE. The option is grayed out. When I try to upload a program I get an error saying I need to select a COM port.

After some google searches I found out about the ch430 driver which solved the problem. Suddenly this stopped working. I reinstalled the driver multiple times, I also reinstalled the IDE, no luck. I checked my device manager but it didn't detect the arduino. A friend told me the problem was the arduino board because it was not an original board. So i bought an original arduino uno but still no luck. I'm sure the usb ports are working because it detects other devices. When I plug in the arduino it doesn't even make the windowns sound. The board does not light up, so it's doesn't even receive power from the laptop. I've tried everything I could think off, and tried everything on the internet but I'm still stuck.

The error message I keep receiving is: avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\COM3": The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: If "the board does not light up", it can be a problem with your USB cable...

Comment: I tried two different cables...